# Find the bounds of two functions containing an absolute value

Tags: definite-integrals

We were given the two functions $f_1(x) = |x|$ and $f_2(x) = x^2-2$ of which we needed to find the surface of. My solution this far is:
[image: My solution]

However, I don't know which bounds I have to use for my integral. When I plotted the graph on my graphic calculator the two bounds were $-2$ and $2$, but I don't know how I could possibly find them without.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: People who make the effort to help you with your question would appreciate it if you also make the effort to post the pictures with the correct orientation.

Comment: @wimi Fixed, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already found the bounds. You have written:

- **First case**, $x\ge 0$:
  $$x^2-x-2=0\implies\begin{cases}x=2\\x=-1\end{cases}$$
  But this first case requires $x\ge 0$ (see two lines above), so the only valid solution is $x=2$.
- **Second case**, $x\le 0$:
  $$x^2+x-2=0\implies\begin{cases}x=1\\x=-2\end{cases}$$
  But this second case requires $x\le 0$ (see two lines above), so the only valid solution is $x=-2$.

There go your two bounds.

Comment: Oh I didn't even pay attention to the condition, my bad. Thank you lots!